# Adjuntar documento en correo con c#

Tags: c#, pdf, email

¿Existe alguna forma de adjuntar un documento previamente creado por iText?

Actualmente tengo puesto un boton que es "Generar oferta", crea el documento por itext, y si tiene un checkbox activado pues te pregunta si quieres enviarlo por email y te abre la app de correo. La cosa es que adjunte el documento creado por itext que ha creado.

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
            if (check_enviaremail.Checked == true)
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show("¿Quieres enviarla por email?", "Atreus - Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:" + tb_email.Text + "");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esta respuesta de SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825950/sending-email-with-attachments-from-c-attachments-arrive-as-part-1-2-in-thunde

Answer (score 3):

Intentaste hacer algo así?

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);

// Aquí construis tu PDF

writer.CloseStream = false;
doc.Close();

// Construis el e-mail

memoryStream.Position = 0;
mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream, "test.pdf"));
```

Esta respuesta esta basada en la de [**brianng**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1196125/5213794) en StackOverflow en inglés.

Por otro lado, te recomiendo que utilices [System.Net.Mail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.mail(v=vs.110).aspx) y [System.Net.Mail.Attachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.mail.attachment(v=vs.110).aspx) en lugar de `mailto` para el envío de e-mail con archivos adjuntos.

Saludos!

Comment: Usando `memoryStream` me tarda como 3 segundos en generar el PDF mientras que sin el es prácticamente instantáneo